# RxJS5 WebSocketSubject and socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io, rxjs5

Can someone please guide me in the right direction for using socket.io with RxJS?
I've been experimenting with my own implementation, but was wondering if there is a preferred standard.

I've seen RxJS5's WebSocketSubject, is there something similar that works with socket.io?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my app is wrap an event form socket io using the fromEventPattern. This way, you get an observable with every event that is being passed to the socket. There is not really a need to have a separate library do this for you I guess.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
   function add (h) {
     socket.on('whatever event you are throwing',h);
   }
);
```